# Launch activity from background app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launching-application

I have my app running in the background and I want the app to be shown on the top(launched) of the android phone when the code below is ran. (I know the code is ran for sure)

This seems like a simple thing but I spent a couple hours on this site and everyone seems to be suggesting something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, myActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, it is not bringing the app to the front and launching it.

I got it to work from a PendingIntent launched from a notification. Which I done by the code below. But I want the app to launch by itself without the user clicking on the notification.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, myActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "title", "msg", contentIntent);
```

I also tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
startActivity(intent);
```

and flagging the intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But doesn't seem to do anything, any help appreciated.

Comment: forgot to mention my android manifest looks like this:
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".myActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: When an activity is defined as LAUNCHER in the manifest it means is the first activity launched when you start the app. So, it is not clear how did you get into a background task without having myActivity launched first.

Comment: MyActivity is launched first, then I either navigate to another app or just hit the home screen to have my app running in the background. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a pending intent and instead of stright up trying to use a intent.
Something like this: seems a lot more simple.

`Intent.send(this, 0, intent);`

Thanks.

Comment: Where is that method `send()` coming from?

Comment: PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
pi.send(this,0,intent);

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to call your own application like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.your.package", "com.your.package.MainActivity");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:** Forgot to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: That's weird, I tested it and worked fine here. I'm starting to suspect it has something to do with android:launchMode="singleInstance" in your manifest

Comment: Have you considered using android:launchMode="singleTop"? singleInstance is not generally recommended according to the SDK docs

Answer (score 1):

Also, I’ve seen since compileSdkVersion 29 it's not possible, unless a few restrictions:

- The activity started very recently.
- The app called `finish()` very recently.
- Through a PendingIntent, but only after a few seconds after the notification was sent.
- The app has been granted the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the user.
  ...

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a **service** that is running in the background and on a certain event, you want your application's activity to come in front i.e. on the users current screen whatever he is doing. It is not advisable to let a background service launch an application without a user's action. The android developer website says

> A status bar notification should be used for any case in which a
>   background service needs to alert the user about an event that
>   requires a response. **A background service should never launch an
>   activity on its own in order to receive user interaction.** The service
>   should instead create a status bar notification that will launch the
>   activity **when selected by the user.**

Hence, do not try to make it launch on its own.

Comment: I see a lot of emergency apps make either a alertdialog or app launch on top of the device though, how do they do that if not this way?

Comment: Exactly, its to be done only for urgent important tasks like an incoming call or alarm. You may use setFullScreenIntent()
`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent, boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

I An not behind my laptop atm so I am nog sure, but I think you have toe pass a context object hand then do context.startactivity(intent);

Sorry for not wel formated I am at my phone atm

Hope It helps

Comment: Tried myActivity.this.startactivity still didn't work, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I am clutching at straws here, but you wrote:

> MyActivity is launched first, then I either navigate to another app or just hit the home screen to have my app running in the background.

So the situation is that your original Activity is NOT running in the background, when you pressed HOME it might well could have been stopped and destroyed. Your background task remained orphan and **MyActivity.this** is **null** at this point.

Try and test what does **Log.i(TAG,MyActivity.this);** print into LogCat.

Comment: It is not null. It returns my.package.myActivity@406447b8