# OneSignal push notification doesn't wake up android

Tags: java, android, node.js, onesignal

I'm making a push notification service using OneSignal API, the problem I stuck at is following : Notification is being received perfectly, but it doesn't wake up my android phone. As i searched in documentation, for IOS, you need to pass content_available : true, to wake it up, but what for Android? Are there something else i need to pass, to wake it up? Using nodejs and express as server. Thanks for answers :)

Comment: over which OS version you are checking ?

Comment: Currently on Android 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893431/1848157 // have a look.

Comment: Hmm.. But I pass app:// url to my notification, and when i click on it, my app opens ( that works fine), but the main question is only about wake lock. Or is it also possible only when a foreground notification is active?