# Android: Start activity from service

Tags: android, service

I made an Android 10 app which has a background service which runs all the time.
I added a feature to remotely call a phone number.
When the corresponding activity is openend, the background service can open the call activity and starts a call.
Problem is, when the activity is closed, the call activity does not show up, no exception, nothing.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Activity:

```
permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
```

Permission is asked on activity open and granted.

Service:

```
                String nr = cmd.substring(Constant.CMD_CALL.length());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + nr));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(intent);
```

logcat:

```
2022-01-29 11:39:35.569 930-3493/? I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity} from uid 10523
2022-01-29 11:39:35.573 930-3493/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Background activity start [callingPackage: com.miachn.familyt3; callingUid: 10523; isCallingUidForeground: false; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10523; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; isBgStartWhitelisted: false; intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{1bb7752 5331:com.miachn.familyt3/u0a523}]
```

EDIT: I have an app installed called cerberus, its an anti theft app. With this one calling from the background works, so there must be a way to do a call from background. It is set as device admin, could this be needed?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks
regards
Erich

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Start An Activity From Background in Android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245398/how-to-start-an-activity-from-background-in-android-10)

Comment: Nobody a hint for me?