# how we open the Activity when app is in background in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calling-convention, tokbox

I am working on the video calling functionality. if first person call the other person then incoming Activity is not open in android 10,Android 11 . i am using overlay permission , but firstly open all applications list. But I want to open directly particular Application permission.

Comment: Please use a high-priority `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following question will help you with this. [Launch activity from background app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744923/launch-activity-from-background-app)

Note: I don't have enough points to add a comment/